# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python

I have this class:

```
class MetricInt(int):
    """Int wrapper that adds only during the observation window."""
    def __new__(cls, _, initial):
        return int.__new__(cls, initial)

    def __init__(self, sim, initial):
        int.__init__(initial)
        self.sim = sim

    def __add__(self, val):
        if self.sim.in_observe_window():
            self = MetricInt(self.sim, super(MetricInt, self).__add__(int(val)))
        return self
```

Which basically overwrite the `__add__` method in order to only to the addition if `self.sim.in_observe_window()` returns `True`.

However, if the initial value is too big, I have :

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long.

What is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do and also handle big numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you on Python 2.6?  You could try subclassing `long` instead.

But in general I strongly suggest not subclassing Python built-in types; CPython reserves the right to skip calls to special methods on such types, and for example will not call `__str__` on a subclass of `str`.  Your example here works, but you might be asking for bugs.

Consider delegating instead, and delegating the operators you want.  (You may also want `__int__`, of course.)

Comment: I have the problem with Python 2.7 but I need my code to be compatible with both Python2 and Python3.

Answer (score 7):

I like Eevee's answer about delegating instead. He has not provided any code so I'm doing it:

```
class MetricInt(object):
    """Int wrapper that adds only during the observation window."""
    def __init__(self, sim, initial):
        self.sim = sim
        self.val = int(initial)

    def __add__(self, val):
        if self.sim.in_observe_window():
            self.val += int(val)
        return self

    def __int__(self):
        return self.val

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.val)
```

This way, the problem is solved. When I decided to subclass the `int` type, it was because I already had a few `int` variables in my code and did not wanted to change my code too much. However, if I define `__int__` and `__float__`, I only need to add some casts to `int`. It's not that bad I guess if it avoids weird bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem casting it to int with int(bigNumber) but in think that is trivial in your case.
You can try with the numpy:

```
numpy.int32(Your big number)
```

And these that I found somewhere that now I can't remember:

```
def int_overflow(val):
  if not -sys.maxint-1 <= val <= sys.maxint:
    val = (val + (sys.maxint + 1)) % (2 * (sys.maxint + 1)) - sys.maxint - 1
  return val
```

Credits to the author.

You can pass the overflowed value throught this function and get it normalized.

Best regards

Comment: Could you explain how and why the function works please?