# "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int" using multiprocessing lib in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, multiprocessing

I am getting the following error message:

```
Process Process-4:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in
_bootstrap self.run()

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File
"/home/maxi1192/Schreibtisch/Firmware/BAT/binaryanalysis_python3/src/bat/bruteforcescan.py",
line 215, in scan (dirname, filename, lenscandir, debug, tags,
scanhints, offsets) = scanqueue.get(timeout=timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 106, in get
if timeout < 0 or not self._poll(timeout):

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 257, in
poll return self._poll(timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 423, in
_poll r = wait([self], timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 912, in
wait ready = selector.select(timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/selectors.py", line 367, in select
fd_event_list = self._poll.poll(timeout)

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int
```

Is this a python3 specific problem? What goes wrong in multiprocessing lib?

Comment: You should post at least some piece of code; best is some executable piece of code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671101/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long)

Comment: Wait packet forever ? Need create time based a `loop` for trying somethings.

Answer (score 0):

This problem tends to happen when mixing 64-bit and 32-bit programs, in this case, the main python program is running in a 64-bit environment but making a function call to a compiled library or program that only handles 32-bit.

Try running your script in a 32-bit version of python OR find out the failing point and find 64-bit versions of it, which is a lot harder. (maybe one of the c-compiled libraries "selectors.py" is using to get the file descriptor event list)