# How to find the inverse log contrast of an image in python

Tags: python-2.7, math, logarithm, exp

I have tried the function `math.exp()`,but it is giving error

```
NewImg[j,k]=a*math.exp(img[j,k])
OverflowError:Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Here `img` is my input image.

Comment: You forgot to upload your image. Here how to do it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: The image is not useful here

Answer (score 0):

Your error is :

```
OverflowError:Python int too large to convert to C long
```

You should look at those question:

- [OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671101/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long)
- [OverflowError Python int too large to convert to C long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114088/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long#22114284)
- [OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174399/overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-float-in-python)

In the last question there is a recommendation to use [`decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) because your `exp()` function is returning a number with many decimals.

```python
from decimal import Decimal
NewImg[j,k]= Decimal(a*math.exp(img[j,k]))
```

Comment: Now, only a black image is appearing in the output.@kenfire

Comment: @neha that is another problem, could you give some more details. Is you `OverflowError` fixed ?

Comment: Yes , OverflowError is fixed.